# convert IP address to bits[]

Tags: php, ip

I want to convert an IP address or subnet mask to bits.
Is there an easy way to do so?
Example:
Input: 255.255.255.0
Output: 11111111 11111111 11111111 00000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ip2long`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) is very useful in this case:

```
$ipAddress = "8.8.8.8";
echo decbin(ip2long($ipAddress));
```

Also, note that `decbin()` won't always output the same number of digits, so try using `sprintf()` instead to always get 32 bits:

```
sprintf("%032b", ip2long($ipAddress));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code i made it for you:

```
$ipAddress = "255.255.255.0";

$ipsArray = explode(".", $ipAddress);

foreach($ipsArray as $ip){
    $ipInt = (int)$ip;

    echo decbin($ipInt) . " "; 
}
```